# How do I get the total rows per group with the Janus GridEx for WinForms?

Tags: winforms, janus, gridex

I am using the Janus GridEx (Windows Forms) and would like to export the contents to Excel.  We have used the export functionality that Janus has built in before, but especially with hierarchical grids the exported file looks unprofessional.

So now we have written our own exporting code and everything is working fine, except that total rows for child tables or groupings are not exported.  The reason for this is that looping through `GridEx.GetRows()` and then recursively through `parentRow.GetChildRows()` does not pick up any of the total rows shown in the grid.

Does anyone know how to get to these total rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looping through .GetRows, you can check the JanusRow.RowType, if it equals Janus.Windows.GridEX.RowType.TotalRow, that row is one with total values in it.

*This is using v3.5 of the Janus Grid

Comment: This only works for total rows for tables - not total rows for groups.  We are by now using Janus version 4.  They might have changed something in the mean time or we might have missed this before.  To get the total rows for groups you need to check for JanusRow.RowType = Janus.Windows.GridEX.RowType.GroupFooter

Answer (score 1):

Use the ASP.NET built in data grid. It will solve your problem.